# How to insert html/ruby snippet into a div using .html()

Tags: jquery, html, ruby

I am trying to insert this code:

```
              Tags: 
              <% @item.all_tags_list.each do |t| %>
                <span class="tag-container">
                  <%= link_to t, tag_path(t) %>
                  <% if @item.tags_from(current_user).include?(t) %>
                    <span>
                      <%= link_to "×", '', class: "remove-tag-button", :'data-tag-name' => t, remote: true %>
                    </span>
                  <% end %>
                </span>
              <% end %>
```

Into a div with an id of tags.  I think I need to use `$('#tags').html()` but how do I do it with correct syntax with all the new lines and going back and forth between ruby and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```js
$('#tags').text('Tags:\n' +
                '<% @item.all_tags_list.each do |t| %>\n' +
                '\t<span class="tag-container">\n' +
                '\t\t<%= link_to t, tag_path(t) %>\n' +
                '\t\t<% if @item.tags_from(current_user).include?(t) %>\n' +
                '\t\t\t<span>\n' +
                '\t\t\t\t<%= link_to "×", \'\', class: "remove-tag-button", :\'data-tag-name\' => t, remote: true %>\n' +
                '\t\t\t</span>\n'+
                '\t\t<% end %>\n' +
                '\t</span>\n' +
                '<% end %>\'');
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<div id="tags" style="white-space: pre;">

</div>
```

Comment: I should have been more specific.  The code is in a .js.erb file in my rails app and turns out all I needed to do was make a partial.  But you did answer my question.  Thanks.